# What happened to my attachment to docker container in VS Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have trouble when I try to attach VS Code to docker. The docker is created by a program used to finish a course named CSCI 0300 by Brown University.

When I do "Attach to Docker" operation, VS Code shows some lines about progress. When appearing such line

> "tart: Run in container: (dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=7014 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=6039 count=1 2>/dev/null) | tar --no-same-owner -xz -C /home/cs300-user/.vscode-server/bin/863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6_1711460417833"

VS Code can't continue to process next step, and shows this

[image]

I have tried to give whole home folder(the files are extracted in home folder).Using `sudo chmod -R 755 ~`